# How I can use a class name here in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to use this for labels which contains `myClass`

```
if ($(field).val() != ""){
  var fieldId = $(field).attr("id");
  $("label[for='"+fieldId+"']").hide();
}
```

The above code is useful to put ID, but how I can use this for classes?

Comment: Do you mean `$("label.myClass")`?

Comment: Thanks for u.You gave the correct answer first

Comment: For the future, you should have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var myClass = "yourclass";
  $("label." + myClass).hide();
```

The jQuery selector `$()` takes strings equivalent to CSS1-3 selectors ([plus a few others](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). So if you can select it via CSS you can select it via jQuery.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but this does not look like a good solution fo the problem OP is having.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Im still trying to work out what his issue is.

Comment: PSR the OP, is a high reputation active user. I'm sure that a comment asking for clarification would get his attention, it's not his first question here. I'd probably just wait until I know exactly what he is looking for before answering. Looks better now though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I find it easier to attempt to answer it, and if the OP doesn't find it useful he can comment on the answer. So he can see what I think he means and correct me accordingly. That's just my way of working.

Comment: That's ok, but if you take that approach you should accept that the answer will often be wrong and people will downvote because of that.

Comment: @Juhana I accept downvoting, I just like to know why. I'm not asking people not to do it just to tell me why, it helps both me and the OP out.

Comment: Thanks for u.I really did not find this answer.It may be the problem with the key words what i had searched

Comment: Thanks to all who gave me support